# How insert multiple row into a table from another table after casting the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, bulkinsert, sql-types

I have a temporary table `#temp` containing all details to insert into a permanent table (named: `Customer`).
The column names of two tables are the same, but datatypes are different
(in `#temp` table all columns datatype is `NVARCHAR`, but in `customer` table columns may be contains `BIT, Date, INT` ect') so I need to cast it before insert into the `customer` table.

This needs to be a dynamic procedure, since I don`t know the column names or datatypes.

Comment: You can directly import from temp. Sql server will do it for example '123' is converted into 123 internally unless and until it found data like 123x.

Comment: If you don't know the datatypes how do you know that your values will be able to be converted to the target datatypes correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
    DECLARE @TargetTableName sysname = 'Customer', 
            @SourceTableName sysname = '#temp'

    -- start the dynamic sql
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = 'INSERT INTO '+ @TargetTableName +' ('

    -- get the columns list
    SELECT @Sql = @Sql + COLUMN_NAME +', '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TargetTableName

    -- remove the last ', ' and add ') SELECT'
    SET @Sql = LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@sql)-2) +') SELECT '

    -- Select the column names and types to create 
    -- CAST(ColumnName As DataType[(Length)]) for each column
    SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'CAST('+ COLUMN_NAME +' As '+ DATA_TYPE + 
                         CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN 
                             '(max)' 
                         WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NOT NULL THEN 
                             '('+ CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as varchar(10)) +')' 
                         ELSE 
                            '' 
                         END +'), '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TargetTableName

    -- remove the last comma and add the FROM clause
    SET @Sql = LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@sql)-1) + ' FROM '+ @SourceTableName

    SELECT @Sql -- this, of course, should be EXEC @Sql, but I recommend leaving it as SELECT or PRINT until you get the exact sql you need.
```

**Note**: for date columns you should to consider using [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) instead of CAST, especially if you know the date format you have in #temp table.